# Where should repetitive logic be placed, in an Express.js app?

Tags: javascript, express, design-patterns

Let's say our API has some functionality, that might be consumed identically from different endpoints/controllers/routes. For example, we might want to perform a login procedure, from different places. Perhaps both post(/login) and post(/register) will eventually log the user in.

So it would make sense, to put this procedure in a different module. For instance, I have this function, in a services/UserLogin class:

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {String} email
 * @param {String} password
 * @return {Promise<Object|false>} Resolves with a User object on success, false on failure.
 */
static login(email, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(
      "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email = ? AND password = ?",
      [email, password],
      async function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
        console.log(results.length);
        if (results.length > 0) {
          // const id = results[0].id/
          const user = results[0];

          resolve(user);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

```
/**
     * 
     * @param {String} token 
     * @return {Promise<Object|false>} Resolves with a userobject on success, false on failure. 
     */
    static async verifyLogin(token){
        const decoded = await Jwt.verifyToken(token);
        if(decoded){
            return decoded
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So I named this class a "service". I'm wondering though, **whether a service is the correct terminology here**. I didn't manage to find a clear definition of this term, in the context of modern web applications. Is it possible, this UserLogin class should better be referred to as a **"facade"**?

I'm sure all of us have found ourselves wondering where to place such functions, and which terminology to use. Can someone give some light on the issue?

Comment: Do you have a User class as that's we're I personally would put it as a static method. Of course there is no one right spot, it is all a matter of personal preference and ease of use/access for other programmer's in the project

Comment: No, in this app we do not have any "models", so i do not have a User class. But, even if we did use something like Sequalize or Mongoose, I'd feel that putting this logic directly in the model would give it slightly too much responsibility. Imagine, that maybe one day i would like to perform some other action within the login method, which is unrelated to the User model.

Comment: What is `db` and where does it come from?

Comment: What underlying interface would you consider the facade to be wrapped around?

Comment: Notice that easily both terms could apply: a service could be implemented using the facade pattern.

Comment: db is just the mysql connection object. We are using "mysql" npm package, no ORM or anything. To be honest I didn't understand your question about the underlying interface. Could you maybe rephrase it?

Comment: @i.brod If you ask whether your code implements a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), I ask you why you did consider that: what other object does the facade wrap? What's the "building" behind the facade?

Comment: Ah, i think i get your point(excuse my ignorance, i'm quite new to the field). Currently this "facade" has references to two objects/modules: this "db", and some small JWT helper(there is another function called verifyLogin, which uses the JWT helper). I wouldn't say it "wraps" them, it just uses them. I edited the code to show it.

Comment: I'd say that if all calls from the endpoints/controllers/routes to the database and/or the JWT helper go through the UserLogin service, then it is a facade. If they call the database themselves directly as well, it's not a facade (or a holey one).